# LibreOffice-Writer, 'space' key not working in ubuntu 14.4

Tags: libreoffice

My LibreOffice writer does not make 'spaces' among words. I am using Ubuntu 14.4. Will someone please explain me whether this happed due to corrupted LibreOffice?

Comment: Is the 'space' key working in other text editors or while typing?

Comment: yes it is working in other text editor.